# Problem with IE8 accelerator

Tags: xml, accelerator

I am trying to make an accelerator to pull up patent documents when the selection is a US patent number. All attempts at installation result in "There was a problem with the Accelerator's information." I am doing my best to follow examples and research possible pitfalls, without success. The xml won't even display in my browser.
My installation file is:

> `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
>   <head>
>       <title>Patent Number Accelerator Install</title>
>   </head>
>   <body>
>       <p>
>            <button id="PatentButton" 
>                        onclick="window.external.AddService('http://homepages.sover.net/~tiplady/PNL.xml')">
>                        Install Patent Number Accelerator
>            </button>
>        </p>
>   </body>
>   </html>`

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My guess: It's simple. You have an unclosed literal in your xml file.

Check the quotation mark after `...PN/{selection}` and you might notice (depending on your font) that the quotation mark is a `”` (Right Double Quotation Mark) with Unicode-codeposition U+201D) while what should be there is a `"` (Quotation Mark with Codeposition U+0022).

This means upon parsing you have an cunlosed string and the xml-file is invalid.